# How do I write a python program to get my Linux machine to restart at a signal?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have one main program "main.py" that may freeze occasionally. Whenever I detect this happens, I want to have a separate program "watch.py" get my Linux machine to restart. These scripts start at bootup automatically since I edited /etc/rc.local.

Right now /etc/rc.local looks like this -

```
python watch.py &
python main.py &
```

This should let both programs run simultaneously. When I notice main.py has frozen, I'll give a signal manually to watch.py (using a remote TCP connection) to restart. What should my python code or shell script be to actually restart the system when "watch.py" receives a signal?

Possible answers could be writing some python code to restart a Linux machine, writing some python code to exit with a certain argument, and upon noticing the argument, execute "sudo reboot".

Comment: Why restart the whole system and not just the process? And it might be worth looking into whether any of the more advanced daemon monitoring tools can detect a hung process and restart it automatically.

Comment: Why restart the process and not just debug it ? ;)

Comment: Well restarting the process sounds like a better idea. Regardless, how should I do it through watch.py? As for debugging it, well the final code should be foolproof of course, but in the meantime, this is what I need. I don't know what errors may happen, but this must run forever, or till the Universe starts contracting again.

Comment: Finishing nail - meet pile driver...

Comment: @xbug: the defense should be layered i.e., you should debug the process and have means to restart it if it gets stuck. There is probably an existing option in upstart or supervisord to restart a process if a heartbeat signal stops.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I was mostly reacting lightly to Etan Reisner's comment, but yes I agree with all of you on the necessity to include some sort of supervision features (or make a good use of the ones already in place), in addition to finding the cause of the problem.

Comment: Does your solution have to be written in python here is some C code that uses SIGHUP signal to interact with a Daemon http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/diff/daemons/daemon_SIGHUP.c.html It's from Michael Kerriscks The Linux Programming Interface (must read book for people programming on Linux IMO). I know nothing about Python so i'm not sure how easy it is to write a signal handler in that languge but ideally you would get your daemon to handle the signal and restart itself if it becomes stuck. As others have mentioned you can the second watch process to trigger off the signal.